# Trying to understand Kempe's algorithm for Graph Coloring

Tags: algorithms, graphs, colorings

I am trying to understand Kempe's algorithm to $k$-color a planar graph. This is what I understand till now:

Trying to 6-color a planer graph ($k=6$)

1. Find a vertex of degree <= 5 ($k-1$)
2. Remove this vertex
3. Color the rest of the graph using a recursive call
4. Put the vertex back, since its degree was at most 5 ($k-1$), we still have at least 1 color left to color this vertex

I understand this procedure but I was curious about the first step: finding a vertex of degree at most $k-1$. What would happen if there is no such vertex in the graph? For example, all vertices have a degree $> k$. In that case will the algorithm fail?

Comment: If all vertices have degree $\ge 6$, can you find a way to $6$-color the graph?  Hint: try a few example graphs and you might spot a method that will always work.

Comment: Recall that there is a result stating that _every planar graph has at least one vertex of degree at most 5_.

Comment: @PålGD I just came across that lemma! it now makes sense to me!